# Align number with decimal position in print c#

Tags: c#, string, printing, alignment, decimal

I have a document to print. I have written  this document with filestream and streamwriter. I want the numbers to be aligned with decimal point.

Eg:

```
      Debit
--------------
200000000.00
     1000.00
       45.00
```

How to achieve this. The line I have used is

```
(Convert.ToInt32(dtNewLedger.Rows[intCount]["Dr"]) > 0 ?  **(bkup.PadString(string.Format("{0,0:n2}", dtNewLedger.Rows[intCount]["Dr"]).ToString().Trim(),40-strByTo.Length, "R"))** : new string(' ', 10) )+ " " +(Convert.ToInt32(dtNewLedger.Rows[intCount]["Cr"]) > 0 ? **(bkup.PadString(string.Format("{0,0:n2}", dtNewLedger.Rows[intCount]["Cr"]).ToString().Trim(), 60-strByTo.Length, "R"))** : new string(' ', 10));
```

Method PadString() is:-

```
public string PadString(string strWorkStr, int intWidth, string strAlign = "", object varCharCode = null)
{
   string strTemp;
   int intWorkStr;
   int intN;
   varCharCode = "";
   strTemp = new string(' ', intWidth);
   intWorkStr = strWorkStr.Length;
   if (varCharCode == "") varCharCode = " ";
   if (strAlign == "") strAlign = "L";

   if (strAlign == "L")
   {
      if ((intWidth > intWorkStr))
         strTemp = strWorkStr + new string(Convert.ToChar(varCharCode), Convert.ToInt32(intWidth - intWorkStr));
      else
         strTemp = strWorkStr.Substring(intWidth);
   }
   else if (strAlign == "R")
   {
      if (intWidth > intWorkStr)
         strTemp = new string(Convert.ToChar(varCharCode), Convert.ToInt32(intWidth - intWorkStr)) + strWorkStr;
      else
         strTemp = strWorkStr.Substring(intWidth);
   }
   else
   {
      if (intWorkStr < intWidth)
      {
         intN = (intWidth - intWorkStr) / 2;
         if ((intWidth - intWorkStr) % 2 == 0)
            strTemp = new string(Convert.ToChar(varCharCode), Convert.ToInt32(intN)) + strWorkStr + new string(Convert.ToChar(varCharCode), Convert.ToInt32(intN));
         else
            strTemp = new string(Convert.ToChar(varCharCode), Convert.ToInt32(intN + 1)) + strWorkStr + new string(Convert.ToChar(varCharCode), Convert.ToInt32(intN));
      }
      else
         strTemp = strWorkStr.Substring(intWidth);
   }
   return strTemp;
}
```

Please help. Please let me know if additional details are required.

Comment: Have a look at the last example in this section: [Using Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#using-standard-numeric-format-strings) : _"Optionally, you can supply an alignment argument to specify the width of the numeric field and whether its value is right- or left-aligned."_

Comment: Have you considered `"1000.00".PadLeft(12)`?

Comment: Tried padleft but its aligning like:                                                                                 
    >1000.00
       > 45.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              >200000000.00

Comment: Tried both but not working. I am unable to paste the output in the got format in comment

Comment: Can you have a look at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2R7Hn1

Comment: Its working when I am executing online. But when applying to my code its not working.       strPrintLine = string.Format("{0,0:n2}",dtNewLedger.Rows[intCount]["Cr"])

Comment: Its a datatable dtNewLedger

Comment: It worked using the link you provided. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Try use string.Format(...)

[Please, read this article.](https://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/formatting-decimals-in-csharp/)

My code example;
e.Graphics.DrawString(String.Format("{0,8:##.00}", debit), fntHeadBold, sb, 700, 205 )